# Gitlab option as a docker image repository

Tags: docker, gitlab

I followed this tutorial to enable gitlab as a repository of docker images, then I executed docker push of the image and it is loaded in gitlab correctly.

http://clusterfrak.com/sysops/app_installs/gitlab_container_registry/

If I go to the Project registry option in Gitlab, the image appears there, but the problem occurs when I restart the coupler engine or the container where gitlab is located and when I re-enter the option to register the project in gitlab, all the images they are eliminated

That could be happening.

Answer (score 1):

> the problem occurs when I restart the coupler engine or the container where gitlab is located and when I re-enter the option to register the project in gitlab, all the images they are eliminated

That means the path where GitLab is storing docker images is part of the container, and is not persistent, ie is not [a volume or a bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/).

From the tutorial, you have the configuration:

```
################
# Registry     #
################
gitlab_rails['registry_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['gitlab_default_projects_features_container_registry'] = false
gitlab_rails['registry_path'] = "/mnt/docker_registry"
gitlab_rails['registry_api_url'] = "https://localhost:5000"
```

You need to make sure, when starting the GitLab container, that it mounts a volume or host local path (which is persistent) to the container internal path `/mnt/docker_registry`.
*Then*, restarting GitLab would allow you to find back all the images you might have stored in the GitLAb-managed Docker registry.

Answer (score 0):

I have created the volume where the images are and now it works.

thank you very much